# Check for base keywords and related ones in a malformated string

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
base = ['Manufacturing', 'Aviation', 'Astronomy', 'Entertaiment', 'Defense & Security']
```

These keywords also have related keywords:

```
related = {'Defense & Security': ['defense', 'security'],
           'Entertaiment': ['soccer', 'sports', 'cinematography'] }
```

I want to search some text using the base keywords and their related keywords. If one of the keywords, or a related keyword, is found, the search should stop, and return the base keyword.

I also want to search even if there is no space between words. For example:

```
keyword = 'Aviation'
search_in = 'detectorshigh intensity lampsbar codeaviation readerphotodiodesview' 

if keyword.lower() in search_in.lower():
     return True
```

The code above will not return `True`, because space between some words doesn't exist, but I want it to return `True`.

Comment: Are you sure? If I run it, it does work

Comment: *I also want to search even if there is no space between words.* `str.find` might be your friend here.

Comment: except for having a `return` outside of a function this code works fine and will print True (after changing `return` to `print`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do:

```py
def getKeywords(search_in, base, related):
    lst=[]

    for w in base:
        if(w.lower() in search_in):
            lst.append(w)
        else:
            for w_r in related.get(w, []):
                if(w_r.lower() in search_in):
                    lst.append(w)
                    break
    return lst

base = ['Manufacturing', 'Aviation', 'Astronomy', 'Entertaiment', 'Defense & Security']

related = {'Defense & Security': ['defense', 'security'],
           'Entertaiment': ['soccer', 'sports', 'cinematography'] }

search_in = 'detectorshigh intensity lampsbar codeaviation readerphotodiodesview' 

print(getKeywords(search_in, base, related))
#outputs: ['Aviation']
```